# Android - BLE connection parameter and Storing BLE sensor data in SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bluetooth-lowenergy, packets

I am developing an Android app that receives data from a BLE sensor at a rate of about 8000 bytes per second.

The connection logic in my app is based upon Google's BluetoothLeGatt sample.  It works. I haven't changed anything and don't explicitly set any connection parameters like interval between connection events (I don't think the Android 4.4 APIs support that).

I am testing on two Android phones, both using Android version 4.4.2 and am using the TI BLE sniffer to monitor BLE traffic.

One phone negotiates a 7.5ms interval and exchanges three 20-byte packets per connection event.  The other phone negotiates 48.75ms between connection events and exchanges nineteen 20-byte packets per event (the effective data transfer rate per second is about the same).

My problem is that I am trying to log the data from the BLE Service activity as it comes in to a SQLite database.  The logging works for the phone with the 7.5ms interval.  However, 
the app locks up for the phone with the 48.75ms interval.  (In general, that phone's connection is a lot less stable).  I assume that's because it is getting processing for 19 packets right on top of each other.

My questions:
1.  Is there anyway I can make both phones (and any future devices) use the 7.5ms interval since that seems to work better?  Is there a way to control  the [Minimum/Maximum_CE_Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983391/ble-number-of-packet-per-connection-interval-in-wireshark) parameters?

2. Is there a better way to log the data than directly from the BLE service activity?  [These SQLite Android Developer pages](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) suggest using an ASync task but that doesn't seem appropriate since the data isn't going to the UI thread.

My code snippets:
This is my connection code [directly from the BluetoothLeGatt sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeService.java)

```
  /**
 * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
 *
 * @param address The device address of the destination device.
 *
 * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
 *         is reported asynchronously through the
 *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 *         callback.
 */
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }
    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}`
```

My logging code is in the broadcastUpdate function:

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder descStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    byte[]  newData = characteristic.getValue();
    String dataString;

    if (newData != null && newData.length > 0) {
        if (UUID_SENSOR_FFF4.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {

            totalDataBytes += newData.length;
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150155/java-gethours-getminutes-and-getseconds
            estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Date timeDiff = new Date(estimatedTime - startTime - 19 * 3600000);
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            descStringBuilder.append("CHAR_FFF4\n");
            descStringBuilder.append("Total Data: " + totalDataBytes + " Bytes\n");
            descStringBuilder.append("Elapsed Time: " + timeFormat.format(timeDiff) + "\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < newData.length; i++){
                byte[] tempArray = { newData[i+1], newData[i] };
                ByteBuffer wrapper = ByteBuffer.wrap(tempArray);
                short tempShort = wrapper.getShort();
                i++;
                stringBuilder.append( tempShort );
                stringBuilder.append( ", ");
            }
            dataString =  stringBuilder.toString();

            values.put(NbmcContract.NmbcDeviceData.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, estimatedTime );
            values.put(NbmcContract.NmbcDeviceData.COLUMN_DATA_STRING, dataString);

            long newRowId = db.insert(NbmcContract.NmbcDeviceData.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            descStringBuilder.append("Row ID: " + newRowId + "\n");


        } else {
            descStringBuilder.append(getCharacteristicString(characteristic) + "\nDATA:  ");

            // We expect these characteristics to return ASCII strings
            if (    DEVICE_NAME_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    MODEL_NUM_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    SERIAL_NUM_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    FIRMWARE_REV_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    HARDWARE_REV_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    FIRMWARE_REV_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    SOFTWARE_REV_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()) ||
                    MANUF_NAME_STRING_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid()))
            {
                for (byte byteChar : newData) {
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%c", byteChar));
                }
            }
            else {
                for (byte byteChar : newData) {
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X", byteChar));
                }
            }
            dataString =  stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        String descString = descStringBuilder.toString();
        intent.putExtra("DESC_STRING", descString);

        UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
        String uuidString = uuid.toString();
        intent.putExtra("CHAR_UUID", uuidString);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", dataString);
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19); write multiple entries in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) on API lvl21+ you can try `bluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(int connectionPriority)`
But that is all you can do.

2)
The BTLE stack on Android is not the best, i would suggest taking the data without any processing and do the processing after all the data has been received. **Please note** that the gatt callbacks happen on a random thread that is NOT your ui-thread. Two calls can originate from two different threads and if one writes into a database and the other comes along and starts to write as well you get a mess.

My suggestion:

On every receiving event you **copy** the `byte[]` array (as Android may reuse the given array for future data) and send it to the main thread with a `Handler`. On the main thread you collect the arrays in a List or Collection and once a certain amount has been collected you start a new thread, give it the list and let it enter the data into a database while the main thread creates a new list for new data.

Comment: Thanks NikkyD.  I agree with you about the Android BTLE stack.  I like the Handler suggestion and will use it the next time I have this much data (we changed the device interface to send less data as a work around).  I'd +1 if I could.